# Trying to change a custom VPN port back to the original on Fortigate 40C

Tags: port, pptp, ios, fortigate, vpn

We recently changed our firewall and bought a Fortigate 40C device. We wanted to use our old VPN settings. The Fortigate support technician told us that this model was new and he didn't know it in detail (or he was still learning networking, I'm not sure anymore) and after a long struggle he configured it to function over the 34443 port and authenticate our users with our AD. Our users had to install Fortigate's sslvpn client to connect. I can't remember the exact reason for this one but somehow the Windows vpn connection didn't manage to connect. This configuration was OK with us as long as it functioned and we were using the system since 3-4 months without any problems.

Recently a new team member joined our team, who is a consultant and is working mostly from home and has a complete iOS based work environment. He has to connect to our system through VPN. As he told us and as we found out ourselves, iOS based systems don't allow changing the VPN port.

Naturally I've tried to change the SSL VPN port to 1723 from 34443. Fortigate doesn't allow me to change it.  It shows this error message: "Entry is used". I tried to change and delete this port from the "Firewall Objects" - "Services" list. It didn't change the outcome.

How should we proceed now? Our last resort will be to install a virtual MS OS on our consultant's system which seems to be far fetched as a solution for such a basic network configuration problem.